Attribute Option label not updating in Magento2
I created a setup Patch file to update the label of attribute options.
Tried below code
Vendor\Custom\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateColorAttributeOptions.php
  <?php

  namespace Vendor\Custom\Setup\Patch\Data;

  use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;
  use Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionLabelInterfaceFactory;
  use Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class UpdateColorAttributeOptions implements DataPatchInterface
 {
  private $moduleDataSetup;
  private $eavConfig;
  private $attributeRepository;
  private $optionLabelFactory;
  private $resource;

  public function __construct(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
    Config $eavConfig,
    AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
    AttributeOptionLabelInterfaceFactory $optionLabelFactory,
    ResourceConnection $resource
) {
    $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    $this->optionLabelFactory = $optionLabelFactory;
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

public function apply()
{
    
    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

    // Define attribute code and the options you want to update
    $attributeCode = 'color'; // Replace with your attribute code
    $optionsToUpdate = [
        'Red Color' => 'Red',
        'Green Color' => 'Green',
    ];

    // Load the attribute
    $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);

   
    $options = $attribute->getOptions();
   
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        foreach ($optionsToUpdate as $oldLabel => $newLabel) {
            if ($option->getLabel() === $oldLabel) {
                /** @var AttributeOptionInterface $option */
                $option->setLabel($newLabel);
                $attribute->setOptions([$option]); 
                $this->attributeRepository->save($attribute);
            }
        }
    }


    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
}

public static function getDependencies()
{
    return [];
}

   public function getAliases()
   {
    return [];
   }
}

The above code is not updating the labels of attribute options, Please someone check and let me know where I am doing wrong.
Thanks in Advance!

I have made it work with below code.
<?php

namespace Vendor\Custom\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionLabelInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class UpdateColorAttributeOptions implements DataPatchInterface
{ 
 private $moduleDataSetup;
 private $eavConfig;
 private $attributeRepository;
 private $optionLabelFactory;
 private $resource;

 public function __construct(
 ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
 Config $eavConfig,
 AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
 AttributeOptionLabelInterfaceFactory $optionLabelFactory,
  ResourceConnection $resource
) {
$this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
$this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
$this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
$this->optionLabelFactory = $optionLabelFactory;
$this->resource = $resource;
 }

public function apply()
{

$this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

// Define attribute code and the options you want to update
$attributeCode = 'color'; // Replace with your attribute code
$optionsToUpdate = [
    'Red Color' => 'Red',
    'Green Color' => 'Green',
];

// Load the attribute
  $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 
   $attributeCode);


   $options = $attribute->getOptions();

   foreach ($options as $option) {
        foreach ($optionsToUpdate as $oldLabel => $newLabel) {
            if ($option->getLabel() === $oldLabel) {
                $option->setLabel($newLabel); 
                $optionId = $option->getValue();
                $attribute->setOption(['value' => [$optionId => 
                [$newLabel]]]);
                $attribute->save();
                break;
            }
        }
    }


  $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
 }

public static function getDependencies()
{
 return [];
}

public function getAliases()
  {
   return [];
  }
}

